# Save/restore column widths in dataTable

Tags: jquery, datatable, column-width

I'd like to create a dataTable with resizeable columns. When the user resizes a column, I would like to store it somewhere in memory, may be cache or session. The next time the user views the table, I want to be able to set the column widths to match their previous settings.

Comment: you can store table column size as json with jquery cookie and restore it after...

Answer (score 1):

Store it in cookie. So next time user visits this page and this cookie is present. You can get use values.